# C# Restarting a thread with a different parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to start a background thread on some user event, in which I wait/sleep 10 seconds to do something if a variable changes between the time it was passed in and the time it is checked. However, during that 10 seconds, the same user event can repeat, and I want to interrupt & reset the thread to use the new variable and start back at 10 seconds.
For example,

```
private static int index = 0;
private static Thread myThread = null;

if(myThread != null && myThread.IsAlive) {
         // need to 'restart' the thread with updated index
         /* Suspend? Resume? */
    } else {
         // create a new thread and start countdown
         myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( some_Thread(index) ));
         myThread.Start();
    }
```

I read that suspend() and resume() are antiquated, and I've read up some posts on Auto/ManualResetEvent, but they're not exactly what I'm looking for. It's probably something closer to Abort() then Start() a new one, but apparently that's unwise.

So any suggestions how to achieve this with one static thread handle? Again, the 10 seconds 'sleep' has to be interruptible and, thereafter, the thread be discardable or restartable. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to start a background thread on some user event,

You are doing what we at SO call an "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)".  You have a completely wrong idea about how to solve a problem and you are asking questions about how to make that wrong way work.  Instead, concentrate on the *user focussed* problem you really have and ask about that.

> in which I wait/sleep 10 seconds to do something if a variable changes between the time it was passed in and the time it is checked.

Don't do any of this stuff. If you're making a thread whose job it is to sleep, odds are good that you are doing something very, very wrong. Threads are expensive; only make a thread if you're going to be scheduling a CPU to service that thread.

When you are considering making a thread, ask yourself "would I hire a worker to do this task?"  Ten seconds of computer time is ten billion nanoseconds; that's like hiring a worker and paying them to sleep for centuries. You'd never do that; you'd just put "do this later" on your to-do list, and come back to it later. If it gets cancelled, you'd take it off your to-do list.

What you want to do instead is make zero extra threads. **Make a cancellable asynchronous workflow that `await`s a `Task.Delay` before it does the work that must be done ten seconds later.** If the user event happens during the delay then cancel the workflow and start a new workflow.

If the work that follows the delay is CPU intensive, *then* schedule a worker thread and await the result. If it is not -- if it is CPU work that comes back in say 30 ms or less -- then just run the work on the main thread.  If it is IO gated, then *use the asynchronous version of the IO API to stay on the main thread*.  You want to be making as few threads as you can get away with here.

Be careful. Even though everything is still on one thread, there are still race conditions that are possible in cancellable workflows like this. You still need to consider all possible interleavings of the non-dependent parts of your asynchronous workflows.

Comment: I'm actually writing a keylogger (for a class, not maliciously) in which the global hook gets called when the user presses a key and was trying to figure out how to flush the buffer to a remote server after some idle time where the user does not press any key but has not yet filled the buffer. I couldn't think of anything other than a thread that would guarantee execution after some delay without requiring the hook to be invoked again; Main() thread hangs after "Application.Run()". I did not know such a thing as this async workflow existed, so thank you! This looks like it'll fit my needs.